# Login with Facebook is not opening Facebook app for Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, fbsdk

In my app there is login with facebook available and working fine. The problem is that it is opening the browser instead of facebook app for Authentication.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:permissions handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
        NSLog(@"Permission denied");
        UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error Occured" message:@"Permission Not Granted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
        [alrt show];
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
    {
        // Handle cancellations
        UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Try Again Later" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
        [alrt show];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

So any idea how to do that?

Comment: which FBSDK version you use and is your problem arise in ios9?

Comment: @RiddhiMakvana no it was the same in iOS 8, now my team lead said me to do it this way :D

Comment: Where did you try this case? Device or Simulator?

Comment: @alicanbatur on device, iPhone 6.

Comment: This method should run facebook app if there is a facebook app installed. If no, sdk looks for browser. Do you have fb app installed at device?

Comment: @alicanbatur Yes, Fb app is installed on my device.